# Can't set the output type on an HEVC decoder IMFTransform

Tags: c++, video, directx-11, ms-media-foundation, hevc

I've written this program to setup an HEVC decoder based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/supporting-direct3d-11-video-decoding-in-media-foundation.  Everything works fine until the end when I call `result = decoder->SetOutputType(0, media_type, 0);`  this returns the error `MF_E_ATTRIBUTENOTFOUND`.  I'm not sure what's wrong, this error isn't described in the SetOutputType documentation and I've only found a couple examples of HEVC decoding with MF and none of them describe an error like this.

```
// WindowsProject5.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mftransform.h>
#include <combaseapi.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <optional>
#include <Mferror.h>

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
  _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

  auto result = CoInitialize(NULL);
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "CoInitialize failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  MSG msg;

  MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO inputInfo{ MFMediaType_Video , MFVideoFormat_HEVC };
  MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO outputInfo{ MFMediaType_Video, MFVideoFormat_NV12 };
  IMFActivate** activates;
  unsigned int numActivates = 255;

  result = MFTEnumEx(MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_DECODER, MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT, &inputInfo, nullptr, &activates, &numActivates);
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "MFTEnum failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  std::cout << numActivates << std::endl;

  if (!numActivates) {
    std::cout << "No HEVC decoders found" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  IMFTransform* decoder;
  result = activates[0]->ActivateObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&decoder));
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "ActivateObject failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  IMFAttributes* attributes;
  result = decoder->GetAttributes(&attributes);
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "GetAttributes failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  auto aware = 123456u;
  result = attributes->GetUINT32(MF_SA_D3D11_AWARE, &aware);
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "GetAttributes failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  std::cout << "MF_SA_D3D11_AWARE = " << aware << std::endl;

  if (!aware) {
    std::cout << "HEVC decoder is not DirectX aware" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  unsigned int resetToken;
  IMFDXGIDeviceManager* deviceManager;

  result = MFCreateDXGIDeviceManager(&resetToken, &deviceManager);
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "MFCreateDXGIDeviceManager failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  result = decoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_SET_D3D_MANAGER, reinterpret_cast<ULONG_PTR>(deviceManager));
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_SET_D3D_MANAGER) failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  ID3D11Device* device;
  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
  ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext;
  result = D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_VIDEO_SUPPORT, nullptr, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &device, &featureLevel, &deviceContext);
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "D3D11CreateDevice failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  result = deviceManager->ResetDevice(device, resetToken);
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "ResetDevice failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  HANDLE deviceHandle;
  result = deviceManager->OpenDeviceHandle(&deviceHandle);
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "OpenDeviceHandle failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  ID3D11VideoDevice* videoDevice;
  result = deviceManager->GetVideoService(deviceHandle, IID_PPV_ARGS(&videoDevice));
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "GetVideoService failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  ID3D11VideoContext* videoContext;
  result = deviceContext->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&videoContext));
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "QueryInterface(videoContext) failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }


  ID3D10Multithread* multithreaded;
  result = device->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&multithreaded));
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "QueryInterface(multithreaded) failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  multithreaded->SetMultithreadProtected(true);

  auto profileCount = videoDevice->GetVideoDecoderProfileCount();
  std::optional<GUID> selectedProfile;
  for (decltype(profileCount) i = 0; i < profileCount; ++i) {
    GUID profile;
    result = videoDevice->GetVideoDecoderProfile(i, &profile);
    if (result != S_OK) {
      std::cout << "GetVideoDecoderProfile(" << i << ") failed" << std::endl;
      std::terminate();
    }
    if (profile == D3D11_DECODER_PROFILE_HEVC_VLD_MAIN) {
      selectedProfile = profile;
      std::cout << "D3D11_DECODER_PROFILE_HEVC_VLD_MAIN found" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (profile == D3D11_DECODER_PROFILE_HEVC_VLD_MAIN10) {
      std::cout << "D3D11_DECODER_PROFILE_HEVC_VLD_MAIN10 found" << std::endl;
    }
  }

  if (!selectedProfile.has_value()) {
    std::cout << "No HEVC decoder profile found" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  BOOL supported;
  result = videoDevice->CheckVideoDecoderFormat(&selectedProfile.value(), DXGI_FORMAT_NV12, &supported);
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "CheckVideoDecoderFormat failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  if (!supported) {
    std::cout << "Decoder format not supported" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  IMFMediaType* media_type;
  result = MFCreateMediaType(&media_type);
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "MFCreateMediaType failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }
  result = media_type->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE) failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }
  result = media_type->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_HEVC);
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE) failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  result = decoder->SetInputType(0, media_type, 0);  // No flags
  if (result != S_OK) {
    std::cout << "SetInputType failed" << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }

  for (uint32_t i = 0;
    SUCCEEDED(decoder->GetOutputAvailableType(0, i, &media_type)); ++i) {
    GUID out_subtype = { 0 };
    result = media_type->GetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, &out_subtype);
    if (result != S_OK) {
      std::cout << "GetGUID failed" << std::endl;
      std::terminate();
    }

    if (out_subtype == MFVideoFormat_NV12) {
      result = decoder->SetOutputType(0, media_type, 0);  // No flags
      if (result != S_OK) {
        std::cout << "SetOutputType failed" << std::endl;
        std::terminate();
      }
      return true;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though MSDN does not mention other input media type attributes in [H.265 / HEVC Video Decoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/h-265---hevc-video-decoder), you need to set them as well. See [H.264 decoder article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/h-264-video-decoder#input-types) on what attributes you need: `MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE` and friends.

You can also use [MFTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/using-mftrace) SDK tool to check what attributes were queried and reported as missing immediately before you get the failure.

```
  // Have this line added:
  MFSetAttributeSize(media_type, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 1280, 720);

  result = decoder->SetInputType(0, media_type, 0);  // No flags
```

Comment: I added MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE to my input type and it worked,  However, I didn't find mftrace very helpful.  When I ran it with "-v -l Debug" all it did with the SetOutputType call was log the attributes of the output media type and the exit error code, nothing about what attribute was queried that caused the error.

Comment: Adding `MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE` fixed it for me as well. I created an issue for documenting this and the store extension [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues/3081)