# Implementing H265/HEVC Decoding with DirectX11 Support

Tags: video, directx-11, ms-media-foundation, hevc

I'm currently using Media Foundation to read and render an H264 video. Adding DX11 support here is very easy:

```
uint32_t resetToken = 0;
ComPtr<IMFDXGIDeviceManager> manager;
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(MFCreateDXGIDeviceManager(&resetToken, &manager));
DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(manager->ResetDevice(getDx11Device(), resetToken));

mVideoAttributes->SetUnknown(MF_SOURCE_READER_D3D_MANAGER, manager.Get());
mVideoAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_SOURCE_READER_ENABLE_ADVANCED_VIDEO_PROCESSING, 1);
mVideoAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS, 1);

DxUtil::ThrowIfFailed(MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(url.data(), mVideoAttributes.Get(), &mSourceReader));
```

Then I just go on to read the buffer and copy it to a texture for rendering.

After no real luck searching, it seems that it's much more involved to get this done for HEVC but can someone give me the genreral gist?

When creating the MFTransform, how do I use my DX11 instance with it? The Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/supporting-direct3d-11-video-decoding-in-media-foundation) says decoding should take place in the IMFTransform::ProcessOutput but with the pure software decoder, this is a method I call, not implement.

Same applies for this method IMFTransform::SetInputType.

I've already looked at this [Can't set the output type on an HEVC decoder IMFTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61996152/cant-set-the-output-type-on-an-hevc-decoder-imftransform) post and it doesn't say where the ID3D11VideoContext etc are actually being used...

Bit clueless and would appreciate any help.

Many thanks!

Comment: H.265/HEVC doecoding setup with Source Reader is exactly the same. You don't need to look into `IMFTransform`.

Comment: You're right. Turns out my Laptop was missing the codec which I just downloaded from Microsoft, and it worked like a charm.